# Как получить список записей в VK

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Хочу написать Android - приложение для работы с аудиозаписями в VK.
Смотрю методы, но никак не найду раздел audio. Может кто подсказать, как получить их?

Я думал, что только общедоступная музыка запрещена, но личные, которые добавил в коллекцию, можно получить через Account, но и там метода нет.

Посмотрел в списке объектов, audio там присутствует, но при клике на ссылку, открывается пустая форма. Такое ощущение, что удалили.

Получается, только через парсинг Web - страницы можно получить Аудиозаписи?

Comment: Секция `audio` закрыта. Но некоторые библиотеки предоставляют обходные решения (например, `vk_api` для `Python`), поэтому получить свои аудиозаписи можно не только через парсинг Web-страницы. Отталкивайтесь от инструментов, которые Вам доступны.

Comment: nomnoms12 смогу ли я выложить приложение в Playmarket, использующий такой обходной (не совсем законный) метод?

Comment: Увы, не знаю. Никогда не занимался разработкой под Android и не связывался с Google Play,